# Node.js console.time() equivalent in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, debugging, execution-time

I have been using the [`console.time()`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_time_label) function in Node.js to measure the execution time of parts of my scripts and it is very very helpful, and in fact very easy to use. But when it comes to PHP, I found that its quite complicated to measure a simple execution time.

Is there any libraries in PHP which is equivalent and simple as `console.time()` in Node.js? Or, is there any simpler way to measure execution time of a part of a PHP code without using the typical `microtime()` difference?

Answer (score 1):

You can use xdebug. It has all those features and it's quite nice. 
You can also do something like this :

```
//start of script
$start = microtime(true);
//do stuff
$end = microtime(true) - $start;
var_dump($end);
```

It will show you the script execution time in microseconds, but I don't find it quite accurate.

EDIT: I did a little digging and I found out about this class http://codeaid.net/php/calculate-script-execution-time-(php-class) . I think if pleases your needs.
There is no easy way or a function to achieve what you are trying to do, you will have to build your own class or dig up something. I suggest using xdebug again.

Comment: Yes this is the typical `microtime()` difference that I mentioned in my question, but if you check the documentation of `console.time()`. You can keep track of multiple timers and can log it based on the name you provide, example `console.time("firstCodeBlock")`. Anyway, I'll check xdebug once.

Comment: in your logs, it will be like `firstCodeBlock: 15ms`, `secondCodeBlock: 20ms` which is very helpful.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out. And yes, I was planning to make my own class for this, but thought I should ask the community before starting. Didn't wanna invent the wheel again.